# How to apply "Substitution Method" in Difference Equations?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, homework

- How to get the value of $y_p(n)$ using substitution method?
- What exactly do we need to substitute to get the value?

[image: Sample Problem for Difference Equation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitution is not a method to obtain the particular solution $y_p(n)$, but the author simply claims that $y_p(n)=e^{-\beta n}u(n)$ *is* a particular solution of the recursion (1.70), and encourages you to *check* his claim by substituting $y_p(n)$ for $y(n)$ in Eq. (1.70) and see if it's correct or not:

$$e^{-\beta n}u(n)=e^{-\beta}e^{-\beta (n-1)}u(n-1)+\delta(n)=e^{-\beta n}u(n-1)+\delta(n)\tag{1}$$

Now check if (1) is satisfied. Distinguish 3 cases: $n<0$, $n=0$, and $n>0$. As a result you should be able to see that (1) (and, therefore, Eq. (1.70)) is satisfied for $y(n)=y_p(n)$, showing that the suggested sequence $y_p(n)$ indeed is a particular solution of (1.70).

Comment: thanks for explaining it to the bits. You made my day. I have one major doubt "how do we deduce the claim like author that 
Yp(n)=(e^−βn) * u(n) is a solution."

Comment: @LusionNectar: You can simply compute the first few elements of $y(n)$ according to the equation. Use the initial condition $y(-1)=0$, then you'll get $y(0)=1$, $y(1)=a$, $y(2)=a^2$, etc. Do you see a pattern?